# I want to pick all sub-tag's values excping only one or more tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have following xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSLT to hanndle this query is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="catalog/cd"/> 
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have written above xslt code which is picking all values of all subtags. Answer of above code will be :

> Empire Burlesque Bob Dylan USA Columbia 10.90 1985

**Question:** I want pick all subtags except one, let us say I don't want value from a subtag "price". i.e I am expecting following answer

> Empire Burlesque Bob Dylan USA Columbia 1985

What will be my **"xslt 1.0"** code for this answer?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be aware that the actual output of your existing XSLT is:

```
<html>
   <body>
           Empire Burlesque
              Bob Dylan
              USA
              Columbia
              10.90
              1985

   </body>
</html>
```

What you show is how a browser would **render** this to the screen (with all white-space character sequences collapsed to a single space).

To exclude the price from the result, you must make your stylesheet go one  level deeper - and also supply your own separators.

Replace:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="catalog/cd"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/*[not(self::price)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The result here will be:

```
<html>
   <body>Empire Burlesque Bob Dylan USA Columbia 1985 </body>
</html>
```

which a browser will render as:

```
Empire Burlesque Bob Dylan USA Columbia 1985
```